# I am not getting the output id is simply loading in the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, partials

i am trying to use the the express routing function but not getting the output when i go to the server it just keeps on loading

```
app.get("/posts/:postname", (req, res) => {
  let requrl = req.params.postname;
  posts.forEach(function (post) {
    let storedtitle = post.title
    if (storedtitle === requrl) {
      app.render("post", {
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content
      })
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: try `res.render` instead of `app.render`. However, there's more problem to it - it's not a good idea to render in a for loop, better to filter the post you need then you render the page.